# How does mysql resolves conflict when same option is configured twice?

Tags: mysql, database-administration

#### /etc/mysql/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
option_1=val_1

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

#### /etc/mysql/conf.d/test.cnf

```
[mysqld]
option_1=val_2
```

As you can see the same option, in this case option_1, is defined twice . Once in the main config file and other time in the include file.
My question is what will mysql treat as the final value of the option_1?

1. val_1
2. val_2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html says in part:

> If multiple instances of a given option are found, the **last instance takes precedence,** with one exception: For mysqld, the first instance of the --user option is used as a security precaution, to prevent a user specified in an option file from being overridden on the command line.

(emphasis mine)

In your example, the option will be set to `val_2`.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to know, Thanks @BillKarwin